# i'm making a count up timer that displays seconds then minute

Tags: python, python-3.x

what i want as an output is

```
1sec
2sec
3sec
.
.
.
1min
0sec
1sec
.
.
.
2min
0sec
```

the code i'm stuck on rn is

```
from time import sleep
i = 0
j = 0
def clockpt1 (i):
   while i < 5:
       print(i, "sec")
       i = i + 1
       sleep(1)
   else:
       i = 0
       clockpt2(j)

def clockpt2(j):
   global j
   j += 1
   print(j,"min")

def clock():
   while True:
       clockpt1(i)

clock()
```

i looked around stackoverflow and apparently using the "global" term is best especially if i want to draw from a global variable and update said variable, but i cant seem to get it to work.

At the same time can someone explain why does "return" not work in this situation?

i get this error

````
 File "clocktest", line 14
   global j
   ^
SyntaxError: name 'j' is parameter and global ```
````

Comment: In your own words, when you write `def clockpt2(j):`, what is the purpose of the `(j)` part?

Comment: Make up your mind: is `j` a function parameter or a global variable?  `return` doesn't work because you lied to the Python interpreter about the interface you want.

Comment: Exactly, i'm a absolute novice so i'm asking. But thanks anyways. I dont know if i need to put the j in clockpt2() parentheses. Much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really think clockpt2 is necessary, so I embedded it in clockpt1

```
from time import sleep
i = 0
j = 0
def clockpt1(i, j):
   while i < 5:
       print(i, "sec")
       i += 1
       sleep(1)
   else:
       i = 0
       j += 1
       print(j, "min", "and", i, "sec")

def clock():
   while True:
       clockpt1(i, j)

clock()
```

Output:

```
0 sec
1 sec
2 sec
3 sec
4 sec
1 min and 0 sec
0 sec
1 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove j from `def clockpt2(j):`

```
from time import sleep
i = 0
j=0
def clockpt1 (i):
       while i < 5:
            print(i, "sec")
            i = i + 1
            sleep(1)
       else:
            i = 0
            clockpt2()

def clockpt2():
        global j
        j += 1
        print(j,"min")
def clock():
       while True:
        clockpt1(i)
clock()
```